# How can I make a div 100% of window height?

Tags: html, css

I just want to have a sidebar that will be 100% of window height, but nothing works except this:

```
#sidebarBack {
background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .3);
position: fixed;
width: 250px;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
}
```

I don't want to have `position: fixed`, because I have horizontally scrollable content, so a fixed part would remain, well, fixed.

Is there any way to do such a thing, maybe with `relative` or `absolute` position?

Here's an quick Fiddle just for a test and explanation:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qtaq7/)

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm a little curious - If you are able to scroll it, doesn't that defeat the idea of making it the height of the page?

Comment: Do you want the sidebar to scroll out of the window, or stay where it is? And hide the scrollable code under the sidebar?

Comment: I want it to scroll out of the window if content is being scrolled. Like a relative/absolute position...

Just like Wordpress admin panel... They have something similar...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**tl;dr** - add `html, body {height:100%;}` to your CSS.

---

Percentage values in CSS are inherited from some ancestor that already has height declared. In your case, you need to tell all parents of your sidebar to be 100% height. I'm assuming that `#sidebarBack` is a direct child of `body`.

Essentially, your code above is telling `#sidebarBack` to be 100% height of its parent. Its parent (we are assuming) is **`body`**, so you need to set `height: 100%;` on `body` as well. We can't stop there, however; `body` inherits height from **`html`**, so we *also* need to set `height: 100%;` on `html`. We can stop here, because `html` inherits its properties from `viewport`, which already has a declared height of `100%`.

This also means if you end up putting the `#sidebar` inside another `div`, then that `div` also needs `height:100%;`.

Here is an **[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qtaq7/4/)**.

Changed your CSS to:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

#sidebar {
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .3);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    float:left;
}

section#settings {
    width:80%;   
    float:left;
    margin-left:100px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm if I add this it makes my content scrollable horizontally and vertically and does not give 100% height to sidebar in relative/absolute position.

Comment: right - a lot of people forget that the tags: html, body, form are still HTML elements that don't have a default height of 100% - they need to be set manually.

Comment: @NenaddvL I'm not sure why you've selected this answer, as it doesn't appear to accomplish what you asked for.  Among other issues, this answer effectively disables all scrolling by setting `position:fixed` on your `#settings` section.  I've added an answer below that I think will be a more complete solution to your problem (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13610461/416630).

Comment: @Darren I have noticed more than one question be marked as a duplicate of this one, so I have added some more information to your answer and revised the question to better serve as a canonical Q&A in the future. Feel free to adjust your answer as you wish to improve it!

Answer (score 44):

You can use the new and so-useful-I-can't-imagine-what-took-W3C-so-long [`vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/length) CSS unit:

```
height:100vh;
```

Comment: and if i have a menu bar on top?

Comment: Why the hell everyone keeps suggesting on using `vh`... If you have a navbar at the top (fixed), you would face a pain on mobile devices, because it would be overlapped by a browser's navbar, and you won't do anything with that.

Answer (score 7):

First, tell the body element to fill the window, rather than shrinking to the size of the content:

```
body { position: absolute; min-height: 100%; }
```

by using `min-height` instead of `height`, body will be allowed to expand beyond the window's height when the content is longer than the window (i.e. this allows for vertical scrolling when needed).

Now, set your "#sidebar" to be `position:absolute`, and use `top:0; bottom:0;` to force it to fill the parent element's vertical space:

```
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .3);
}
```

Here are a couple of jsFiddles:

- [with content shorter than the window](http://jsfiddle.net/Qtaq7/7/)
- [with content longer than the window](http://jsfiddle.net/Qtaq7/8/)

As you'll see, in both examples, I've preserved your width setting on the "#settings" section, thus showing that horizontal scrolling works as you requested.

Comment: I am having issues with every single answer. None actually resolves the problem. Except checked answer if I replace his fixed to absolute position on #settings.

However neither that way it is good because html, body 100% gives me scrollable page in height and that is now what I want.
I think I will change design and positions because it definetly does not go this way. Thanks for your help too!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#sidebarBack {
 background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .3);
 position: fixed;
 width: 250px;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm not quitely what I need. It remain fixed and just pulls it over header because of top:0;

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
html,body{height:100%;}
#sidebar {
background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .3);
/*position: fixed;*/
width: 100px;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
float:left;
}


section#settings {
width: 62%;
height: auto;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin-left: 100px;
float:left;
}
```

​

Comment: Doesn't make sidebar 100% height still :(