# Stretch child div height to fill parent that has dynamic height

Tags: css, html

As it can be seen in the following fiddle, I have two `div`s, contained in a parent `div` that have stretched to contain the big div, my goal is to make those child `div`s equal in height.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/y9bM4/

[image]

Comment: check those questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049783/how-to-make-a-floated-div-100-height-of-its-parent, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609531/make-an-div-100-height-css

Comment: @MikeHometchko there are many on CSS but not on CSS3. I think so.

Comment: @Mr_Green the differences at a fundamental level between "CSS" and CSS3 are trivial so I don't see the issue.  This is a very common issue that has been asked and answered to death.

Comment: @MikeHometchko check my solution. I am sure no one has answered the same before.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The solution is to use `display: table-cell` to bring those elements inline instead of using `display: inline-block` or `float: left`.

```css
div#container {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #F1F1F1
}
.content {
  width: 150px;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.text {
  font-family: 12px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>

    <div class="text">Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text.
      <br>Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text.
      <br>Sample Text.
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Title 2</h1>

    <div class="text">Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text. Sample Text.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/y9bM4/14/)

Comment: This doesn't work if the parent element is table cell though.

Answer (score 70):

Use `display: flex` to stretch your `div`s:

```
div#container {
    padding:20px;
    background:#F1F1F1;
    display: flex;
}

.content {
    width:150px;
    background:#ddd;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lampt2509/m7tu4c25/4/)

Answer (score 31):

Add the following CSS:

For the parent div:

```
style="display: flex;"
```

For child div:

```
style="align-items: stretch;"
```

Comment: I needed to add the `stretch` on the children for flex to work for me.

Comment: That's works for me, but for  `display: grid` which is inside stretched element, I have to add `height: 100%` parameter. The grid contains dynamic height by default also.

Answer (score 9):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV8B24rSN5o

I think you can use display as grid:

```
.parent { display: grid };
```

Comment: Did you test your answer using the original poster's same code?

Comment: It works and doesn't require any CSS on the child. That's because a CSS Grid cell will have `auto` row and cell by default. It actually works pretty nicely with IE if you use `display: -ms-grid` to avoid some flexbugs, as long you only have one child.

Answer (score 0):

Add Display:flex to parent, and Align-items: stretch; to child, if you need to cover up the space with elements then also add justify-content: space-between.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -8):

You can do it easily with a bit of jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var parentHeight = $("#parentDiv").parent().height();
  $("#childDiv").height(parentHeight);
});
```

Comment: Although once the browser window is resized this will break, whereas the CSS ones will still work.