# Change body height based on dynamic header height

Tags: html, css

I have a layout with a top section which can grow in height, and a content section below which contains a chart. The basic HTML structure can be characterized as:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top">
        <span class="box">Box 0</span>
        <span class="box new">
            <button>+</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="chart">
       Chart
    </div>
</div>
```

Each `box` element is a fixed width and height, and is a fluid design so that as the boxes cannot fit onto the same line, they wrap round to the next, making their container (`top`) grow.

Here is an interactive demo at this stage: http://jsfiddle.net/d1d6bwbc/ where you can see that the `wrapper` is 100% width & height (red border). The `top` has a magenta border, and grows as the boxes need to wrap and the `chart` has a blue border.

I am trying to make that `chart` element fill 100% of the remaining height in `wrapper`.

Here is my css so far

```
body{margin:0}
.wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:calc(100% - 2px); /* account for border in this example */
    width:calc(100% - 2px); /* account for border in this example */
}

.top{
    border: 1px solid magenta;
    padding-bottom:5px
}

#chart{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    /* style chart to fill 100% of wrapper
}
```

I have tried numerous css hacks and tricks, such as those found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900122/stretch-child-div-height-to-fill-parent-that-has-dynamic-height) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581799/how-to-stretch-div-height-to-fill-parent-div-css) but they do not seem to work on my layout.

I have complete control over the layout so if my markup requires some work that will be fine, but a simple way to achieve a fill on that `chart` element is what I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a perfect case for CSS table layout. Set the wrapper as `table`, top and bottom box as `table-row`, and the bottom box with `height:100%` that pushes the top box to its minimal height to fit the content inside.

```js
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.boxes = ko.observableArray([new Box(0)]);

    self.addBox = function () {
        self.boxes.push(new Box(self.boxes().length));
    }
}

function Box(index) {
    self.text = "Box " + index;
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.top {
    border: 1px solid magenta;
    display: table-row;
}
#chart {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}
.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 5px;
}
.box.new {
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
.box.new button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top">
        <!-- ko foreach:boxes -->
        <span class="box" data-bind="text:text">            
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <span class="box new">
            <button data-bind="click:addBox">+</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="chart">
       Chart
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d1d6bwbc/4/

Comment: genius, I was just trying to play around with table layouts

Comment: Genius, indeed. and browser support is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this behavior is achievable via pure CSS .
But it is easy to create using javascript.
I've added this JS to your example

```
var Fill = function (){
    var top =document.getElementById("top").offsetHeight;
    var wrapper =document.getElementById("wrapper").clientHeight;
    document.getElementById("chart").setAttribute("style","height:"+(wrapper-top-1)+"px");

}

var addEvent = function(elem, type, eventHandle) {
    if (elem == null || typeof(elem) == 'undefined') return;
    if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
        elem.addEventListener( type, eventHandle, false );
    } else if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
        elem.attachEvent( "on" + type, eventHandle );
    } else {
        elem["on"+type]=eventHandle;
    }
};

addEvent(window, "resize", Fill);
Fill();
```

and also edited the addBox function to fire the event

```
self.addBox = function(){
        self.boxes.push(new Box(self.boxes().length));
        Fill();
    }
```

I also Had to add id's to `top` and `wrapper` for this example but you can use class obviously.

Here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d1d6bwbc/3/)

Comment: Thanks, thats a good workaround. Ill adapt it easily to my situation if there isn't a pure css fix for this.