# CSS rule not applying 100% to height

Tags: css

This CSS rule not working..

```
#wrapper{
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

The wrapper does not take the full height of the page..

Comment: 100%  of WHAT? - Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is **wrapper** ?

Comment: you should spend a more couple of minutes more and look at the post preview to give a better formatting and a context to your question

Comment: I am trying to create a div for which I set the height should be same as that of my page.

Comment: body{
 background-color: aliceblue;
}

remove the question  , there are many duplicates

Comment: wrapper is the id of the div.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609531/how-can-i-make-a-div-100-of-window-height

Comment: then use `#wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

Just try like below it will be work for your issue.

First, pick the `div` which was you want to make 100% height of your any device and then apply CSS like below.

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

For make your `section` or `div` height same as well as your device height you have to use `VH`, It's called `viewport height`.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a div for which I set the height should be same as that of my page.

```
height:100%
```

means nothing by itself...it hs to be 100% of *something*..and those numbers have to be calculable all the way up the parent-child chain.

So what can the wrapper be 100% of? The answer is the `<body>` which itself is a child of the `<html>` element.

Once we set those, it all works as you can't go up the chain any further than the `<html>` element which is the height of the viewport.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

That said, I'd go with `min-height:100%` on the wrapper to allow for overflow issues if the content exceeds the vireport height.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.expander {
  height:1000px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="expander"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <style>
     img.normal {
     height: auto;
     }
     img.big {
     height: 500px;
     }
     p.ex {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
     }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="normal" height="84" src="hari.jpg" width="95"><br>
    <img class="big" height="84" src="hari.jpg" width="95">
    <p class="ex">
        sample
    </p>
</body>
```