# Making a 100% height div

Tags: html, css

I'm making my first steps learning to code. I've been taking some courses on Internet and now I decided to continue learning while I build a Wordpress child theme.

The thing is that I have two divs, I want that my first div (an image) takes the 100% of the height of my window. Then if I scroll down I can see the second div (body text).

In fact, it's the same effect that uses the MOMA site http://www.moma.org/calendar/exhibitions/1614

Navigating through S.O I found a question really similar to this one ith a similar objective:   [How can I make a div 100% of window height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609531/how-can-i-make-a-div-100-of-window-height/13610461#13610461)

From here I started to make my own version but even using a `height: 100%` it doesn't work:

```css
.image {

    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 100;
    padding:40px;

}

.text {
    
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: roboto;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    line-height: normal;
    display: block;

}
```

```html
<div id="image">

<img src="https://www.discovernorthernireland.com/image.aspx?ImageID=59529&Width=600&Height=400&Bg=">

        </div>

<div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius sapiente voluptatem deleniti sunt quos earum distinctio ea eaque dolore velit optio aliquid nihil quia qui dignissimos tempora dolorem. Voluptates voluptate.</p>
            
</div>
```

I can't make my image stay vertically and horizontally centered in the browser. Alone without the text immediately after.

Do you have some suggestion? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question, but I assume you want a full-screen image depending on the size of the viewport? You might want to look into using 'vh' and 'vw': https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Comment: Is this what you were trying to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/0r4mxqeu/4/

Comment: exactlty! Thank you very much @adamk22